# Ionic 2+, iOS only issue: resetting plugins due to page load

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic2, ionic3

I have a very strange issue in my ionic 3 app.  I'm adding a feature to an app, and the feature involves a multi-step input process using Angular 2+ forms and validators.  All was fine on web, Android and older iOS devices (iOS 9).  On iOS 10 I get the following after submitting my first form step:

```
Resetting plugins due to page load
```

Then the app re-starts.  The main trigger point seems to be setting a boolean after this first step which hides the first form and shows the second.  Commenting out that one line prevents the issue.

Is there something I can do to find more information about why this error is being thrown in iOS 10 only?  Extra logging, for example?

**HTML**

```
<ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
        <ion-icon name="person-add"></ion-icon> Sign Up!
    </ion-card-header>

    <!--Step 1 - confirm user-->
    <ion-list no-lines *ngIf="!hasConfirmedStep1">
      <form [formGroup]="formStepOne">

       <...SNIP...>

        <ion-item>
          <button ion-button icon-right float-right small (click)="checkUser()" [disabled]="!formStepOne.valid">
            Next
            <ion-icon name="arrow-round-forward"></ion-icon>      
          </button>
        </ion-item>
      </form>
    </ion-list>

    <!--Step 2...Create Account-->
    <ion-list no-lines *ngIf="hasConfirmedStep1 && !hasConfirmedStep2">
      <form [formGroup]="formStepTwo">


        <!--Email/Confirm email-->
        <div formGroupName="validEmail">

        <...SNIP...>

        </div>
        <ion-item>
          <button ion-button icon-right float-right small (click)="createUser()" [disabled]="!formStepTwo.valid">
            Next
            <ion-icon name="arrow-round-forward"></ion-icon>      
          </button>
        </ion-item>
      </form>

    </ion-list>
</ion-card>
```

**TS**

```
async checkUser() {

    this.hasSubmittedStep1 = true;
    this.errorMessage = this.successMessage = "";

    if (!this.formStepOne.valid) {
      this.loggingService.debug("Invalid signup form for Check User");
      this.errorMessage = "Please enter valid input.";
    }
    else {
      this.loggingService.debug("Valid signup form for Check User.  Checking info...");

      //Confirm User


      this.successMessage = 'Confirmed!  Please Create Account.';
      this.hasConfirmedStep1 = true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but on iOS 10 the issue seemed to be hiding the HTML `[formGroup]` tags.  This page constructor uses `formBuilder.group()` to instantiate objects for these forms.  Maybe something on iOS 10 expects there to be HTML forms associated with these?

My fix was to simply re-structure the page so that the `<form>` tags were always displayed, but within them I had a `<div>` that I placed the `*ngIf` on to show/hide the interior visual elements.  Strange, but seems to work.

Comment: wow,, great,, working well too,,  thanks for save lot of hours :)